# How to work with Javascript url keys in object

Tags: javascript

I have the below object

```
websites=
{
"https://google.com": "google",
"https://wix.com/myprofile":"wix",
"https://stackoverflow.com": "stackoverflow"
}
```

How to access the values (google, wix, stackoverflow)by using javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the values by accessing `Object[key]` like this:

```js
let websites=
{
"https://google.com": "google",
"https://wix.com/myprofile":"wix",
"https://stackoverflow.com": "stackoverflow"
};

console.log(websites['https://google.com']);
```

Comment: I would like to access the value of "google" by using input."https://google.com". Can I know how to do it?

Comment: Where do you want to give the input? Some textfield or some other form of input?

Comment: I would like to access the values which are in simple plain text where the keys are the url's.

Comment: The above code looks good. that works for me. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Easily:

```
function getWebsite(input) {
    for (let item in websites) {
        let rawItem = item.split("/");
        if (rawItem.indexOf(input) >= 0) return websites[item];
    }
}

websites=
{
"https://google.com": "google",
"https://wix.com/myprofile":"wix",
"https://stackoverflow.com": "stackoverflow"
}

console.log(getWebsite("google.com"));
console.log(getWebsite("wix.com"));
console.log(getWebsite("stackoverflow.com"));
```